# Problema modificando state en React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Estoy haciendo un registro de turnos ficticio para un aeroclub. La finalidad es que un usuario pueda entrar a la pagina elija un avion, un horario y se agregue este registro a una lista.

El aeroclub abre de 10 a 18 hs, entonces cada avion tiene una planilla de 10 a 18 para ocupar de un turno por hora.

El problema lo estoy teniendo cuando se elije un turno para volar X avion y este horario deberia dejar de estar disponible en la lista, no puedo lograr eso.

Podrian darme una mano con esto? Copio aca abajo el codigo que estoy usando con los comentarios.

```
//Primero informamos el horario completo del aeroclub.

const horarioCompleto = [10,11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]

//Determinamos que aviones estan disponibles y en que horario.

const [avionesDisponibles, setAvionesDisponibles] = useState([
    {
        nombre: "C-150",
        horasDisponibles: [horarioCompleto]
    },
    {
        nombre: "C-152",
        horasDisponibles: [horarioCompleto]
    },
    {
        nombre: "Archer",
        horasDisponibles: [horarioCompleto]
    },
    {
        nombre: "Simulador",
        horasDisponibles: [horarioCompleto]
    }
])

//Mostramos los aviones en el form

const NOMBRES_AVIONES = avionesDisponibles.map(e => {
    return <option>{e.nombre}</option>
})

//El usuario elije su avion con uno de los options recien generados. Por defecto tenemos al C-150.

const [avionElegido, setAvionElegido] = useState("C-150")

let objetoAvion = avionesDisponibles.filter(e => e.nombre === avionElegido)

let turnosAvion = objetoAvion.map(e => e.horasDisponibles.map(e => e.map(e => {
    return <option>{e}</option>
})))


//Los valores "horaElegida", "avionElegido" e "instructor" van a determinar las caracteristicas del turno.

const [horaElegida, setHoraElegida] = useState(10)

const [instructor, setInstructor] = useState(false)

//Con la funcion agregarTurno formulamos el turno y lo renderizamos en la pantalla.

const [listaDeTurnos, setListaDeTurnos] = useState([])

const agregarTurno = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setListaDeTurnos(prev => [...prev,
        <li>{horaElegida}:00 hs | {avionElegido} | {instructor ? "Con instructor" : "Solo"}</li>
    ])
}
```

Abajo, en el componente, tenemos este form:

```
<form>
 <h2>Avion</h2>
    <select onChange={(event) => setAvionElegido(event.target.value)}>
       {NOMBRES_AVIONES}
    </select>
           <h2>Horarios disponibles</h2>
        <select onChange={(event) => setHoraElegida(event.target.value)}>
          {turnosAvion[0][0]}
      </select>
     <label>
     Con instructor
   <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => setInstructor(prev => !prev)} />
 </label>
<button onClick={agregarTurno}>Solicitar</button>
</form>
```

En la ultima parte (la funcion agregarTurno) estoy probando con varias cosas para llamar a la funcion setAvionesDisponibles y modificar el objeto particular del avion que se esta seleccionando pero no doy con la forma correcta.

Hago un edit con el codigo con el que intente:

```
const agregarTurno = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setListaDeTurnos(prev => [...prev,
        <li>{horaElegida}:00 hs | {avionElegido} | {instructor ? "Con instructor" : "Solo"}</li>
    ])
    setAvionesDisponibles(prev => [...prev.filter(e => e.nombre === avionElegido)[0].horasDisponibles[0].filter(e => e !== Number(horaElegida))])
}
```

Desde ya, un millón de gracias.